# Eclipse doesn't start in windows 10

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse doesn't start in windows 10. When I click on Eclipse, it just appears for a second and closes quickly. But previously I worked properly.

Comment: ok? haven't had any problems with it. anyway, tried un- and re-installing?

Comment: Restart computer? Re-download eclipse? Does the workspace-choser show up? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Run eclipse from the command-line. It is most likely throwing an exception/error. Capture that exception and update this question with it. (It's unlikely to be due to Window 10.)

Comment: Also check possible `hs_err*.log` files in the Eclipse installation folder (the one where `eclipse.exe` is). I would also try to Run as administrator.

Comment: Could it be that you're trying to use the 32-bits version of Eclipse on a 64-bits JVM? Is Java working as expected and return good content if you check `java -version`? Also, is it the latest version of Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 0):

just reinstalling  JRE ,I have solve it

Answer (score 0):

If your Eclipse is 64 bit then make sure you have JRE 64 bit installed and it is latest one and if your Eclipse is 32 bit then you need latest 32bit JRE to work

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall eclipse than check you's system configuration than install 32 bit or 64 bit according to  your system compatible. Make sure **eclipses and JDK both shared same bits**.